# Does Readlist give maximum its speed?

Tags: import

Trying to understand if `ReadList` can be seed-up. I have a text file with columns of strings and numbers, some of numbers are in Fortan form. To import that in Mathematica I use command like:

```
ReadList["path_to_file",{Word,Word,Number,Number,Number}]
```

with appropriate numbers of `Word` and `Number` depending on concrete file (they can vary). With a file of about 35000 rows and 30 columns it takes about 1 second. Is this a decent speed? Could it be improved further?

Comment: Do you *need* it to be faster? 1s is pretty fast for most things...

Comment: @MarcoB, I'm just curious if there are some tricks/technics for fast import txt files.

Comment: If I was interested in this I'd be trying to measure the time to read the same file with whatever was the fastest non-Mathematica tool I could find (I dunno, `cat` or something) to see if I could figure out the overhead of using Mathematica and then decide whether or not `ReadList` is fast (enough).  Probably have to work with much larger files to get useful numbers though.